# Change "Google.co.uk" to "Google.com"

Tags: opera, search-engines

My Opera uses "Google.co.uk" instead of "Google.com" for searching. How can I change it to "Google.com" as default search engine? (with auto-suggest feature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change it on Windows 7 this way:

Edit the `default_partner_content.json` file located at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\(Version)\resources\`

Or if you installed it in another place, then the `resources\` folder is the same place where `Opera.exe` is located.

For the UK, the thing you are looking for is this sequence:

```
  "gb": {
    "other": {
      "list": [
        "google_uk",
        "yahoo",
        "bing",
        "amazon",
        "wiki"
      ],
      "speed_dial_index_list": [0]
    }
  },
```

just change `"google_uk"` to `"google_com"` there.

Everyone else, just look for your country on that list and edit it. I also changed the Wikipedia search, to look for articles in English.

**Or**, you could redefine what "google_uk" means. Look for `www.google.co.uk`, and switch it to `www.google.com`.

Everyone else, just replace the domains you have, with the ones you want to have.

Save, then re-launch Opera, and enjoy.

Comment: Mine was in C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\(version)\resources

Comment: Now I did this, and when I want to launch opera I get an error: `At least one file with recources (.pak) is corrupted. Please reinstall opera.`

Comment: Modifying this file in any way will result in the error

Comment: Opera has probably closed off their infrastructure even more. They've been losing transparency every year, which made me switch to Vivaldi.

Comment: Yeah well, I also tried this https://forums.opera.com/topic/2242/using-google-com-instead-of-google-xx and it didn't work, it suggested editing C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable

Comment: Because every time I changed anything in the json file it would get replaced with whatever it was before/

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cookie so that your results are always global.

Just add NCR after the Google.com/  . this will set the cookie for global Google site. So next time the results will not be localized based on your country

http://google.com/ncr

Comment: That cookie is probably utilized by Google. But Opera is opening directly ```google.co.uk```, so it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

We are going to search for a file named `Local State`, it could be in a different location based on your installation (depending on where you installed the program).

Open up Opera, click on the `O` icon on top left sidebar, click on `Help -> About Opera`. On the opened window, under `Browser Identification`, you will see `Paths`. Copy and open the `Profile Paths` in `Windows Explorer`, and edit the `Local State` file with your favorite text editor:

Here's where I found mine:

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Local State
```

Search for `country` and `country_from_server` and edit `GB` to `US` for both of them.

```
"location":{"country":"GB","country_from_server":"GB"}
```

Change it to:

```
"location":{"country":"US","country_from_server":"US"}
```

US will use `google.com`, but if you want to change it something else, here is a list with ISO country codes:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53547_01/opera_5_04_03_core_help/iso_and_country_codes_23428_1.htm

Comment: Source: https://forums.opera.com/topic/7304/wrong-google-country/2

Answer (score -1):

Country is based on your default Opera language.

To change it, click on "Preferred Languages" button in Settings / Browser / Language, choose your preferred language.

[Preferred Languages screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cS7C.png)

Restart Opera and this should work as expected.

Comment: I don't think so. I have it configured to use U.S. English, but it's still opening ```google.co.uk```. It's trying to detect your IP address and geo-locate it, so when you're using a VPN/proxy, it geo-locates it instead.